# What is __builtin_apply_args return format?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

I'm experimenting with library analysis, and I'm trying to understand what `__builtin_apply_args` returns.
I know it's a `void*`, and that the magic size seems to be 512.
Example hex dump:

```
CE 1C 94 20 00 00 7F FE 00 00 03 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 58 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C0 01 28 00 80 00 00 00 80 00 00 00 C0 01 69 00 C0 01 69 00 00 00 01 C3 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 4B 00 00 00 00 C0 01 76 00 00 00 00 CB 00 00 00 00 C0 01 76 00 00 00 01 4B 00 00 00 00 C0 02 69 00 00 00 01 C1 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C0 01 69 00 00 00 01 B1 00 00 00 00 C0 01 69 00 C0 01 69 00 00 00 01 C3 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 45 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 CE 1C 93 30 00 00 7F FE CE 1C 92 B0 00 00 7F FE 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 CE 1C 94 60 00 00 7F FE 00 42 43 FF 00 00 00 00 CE 1C 95 60 00 00 7F FE C4 38 A8 B3 00 00 7F 11 C4 6C F4 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 03 E8 3B 5D B0 F6 00 46 85 44 00 00 00 00 13 0D E4 C5 41 69 D2 39 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 A8 5A A0 00 00 00 00 CE 1C 94 80 00 00 7F FE 00 42 69 82 00 00 00 00 CE 1C 95 68 00 00 7F FE 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C4 33 1E C5 00 00 7F 11 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 CE 1C 95 68 00 00 7F FE 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 42 46 CA 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 85 82 C8 E7 74 CD 3A 7A 00 40 5C D0 00 00 00 00 CE 1C 95 60 00 00 7F FE 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 AC A2 C8 E7 8B 30 A6 43 B9 78 C8 E7 8A EE B2 1C 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 46 3F 30 00 00 00 00 CE 1C 95 68 00 00 7F FE 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

This particular call seems to start always with CE1C and then a 94 or 93. Then a 20 or a 60. On it goes, it seems to have the value of each argument twice at some point. This call in particular is 2 4-byte integers and 2 8-byte integers.

System: Linux 64-bit x86_64

Comment: I assume that depends on OS/target which you have forgotten to specify. The exact details should be there in the gcc source.

Comment: I'll take a look, thanks Jester.